# How do I apply some commits to the master branch if its latest commit has been amended?

Tags: git

I have a `master` branch with, say, 3 commits:

```
A -> B -> C
```

I branched off from it, and now I have a `develop` branch with 6 commits:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
```

After the branch `develop` was created, in the `master` branch I have edited commit `C` with `git commit --amend`. Now I want to apply commits `D` to `F` in the `master` branch. How do I do it without making too much of a mess since `D` started from a commit that was slightly different from the one on `master`?

Comment: `man git-cherry-pick` Since you only have 2 commits, that is probably your best bet.

Comment: Does `rebase master` not work cleanly?

Comment: Try (in the deveop branch) `git rebase -i master`, prune E, then switch to master and fast forward

Comment: I do not want to discard E. I want to apply D to F, i.e. D, E, F.

Comment: Then `git rebase master` should work just fine.  Then switch to master and merge.

Comment: What if I didn't want a "merge" commit? I'd like to have a history where the commits feel like they've been made directly on the master branch

Comment: `git merge --ff-only`

Comment: git commit --amend will destroy C and create C', with a different SHA. Bear that in mind...

Comment: @DaemonPainter The previous commit is not destroyed, just pruned from the branch.  A subsequent garbage collection may delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick other-branch~3..other-branch # apply the last 3 commits from the other branch
```

That should do.

Comment: I did this while I was on `master`, and now my `develop` has the unified history that I thought would go to `master`, while `master` is untouched. Did I mess something up?

Comment: I hadn't noticed it was master that you wanted to move. While on master you can do: `git merge other-branch`